# Custom Post Type And "fopen"

Tags: custom-post-types, search, thumbnails

Never posted here but since I can't find a solution on my own, let's abuse your kindness!

I'm adding some custom post types through my theme.

The first custom type works like a charm, but as soon as I add the second (and third) one, the apache's error log reports a PHP Warning when trying to do a search action (like the one to search a post to attach a media).

```
fopen(http://localhost/site/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream [...] in E:\\www\\site\\wp-includes\\class-http.php on line 876, referer: http://localhost/raw/wp-admin/edit.php
```

It only happens when I set the 'thumbnail' string into the $args['supports'] array passed to the register_post_type function.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I had that error pop up a few times recently as well.  From what I can tell it's a side effect of the local dev environment.

More reading:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-30-warning-fopenhttpabccomwp-cronphpdoing_wp_cron

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11831

Comment: I've had this as well.  From the Trac ticket, adding `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` to my wp-config.php silenced the warning.